# c++ employee name search

Tags: c++, c++11, search, binary-search

```
        string name[size] = {"Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Michalski, Joe", "Griffin, Jim",
                "Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", "Taylor, Tyrone", "Johnson, Jill",
                "Allison, Jeff", "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill", "Whitman, Jean",
                "Moretti, Bella", "Wu, Hong", "Patel, Renee", "Harrison, Rose",
                "Smith, Cathy", "Conroy, Pat", "Kelly, Sean", "Holland, Beth"};



    int binarySearchIterative(string name[], int size, string empName) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = size - 1;

        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (empName == name[mid]) {
                return mid;
            } else if (empName < name[mid]) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

So when I type in a name to search for, I have to type it in exactly as listed in the array. For example, if I want to find Bill Collins. I have to type it as Collins, Bill. If I were to type in Bill Collins, it would tell me that the employee is not found. I need to be able to search the name First Last, and also without using the comma. If you need to see more of my code let me know.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: You'll want to split those names up because literally nobody will type them in exactly that way.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Binary search requires a sorted input, and you can check this easily with a pencil test:

Suppose you have a series of numbers like `1,5,8,10,12`, and you are looking for `5`; First guess, you split the series and test the number in the middle, i.e. `8`. Since `5` is lower than `8`, it is clear that you don't have to look for `5` in the half above the `8`. Yet this assumption only holds if the series is sorted; otherwise the `5` might be in the upper part as well.

So sort your input, and then see if it works. Otherwise use a debugger :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a comparison function (or code), that extracts the first name and last name (as separate variables) from the string.

Once extracted, you can easily compare by first name or last name.

Ideally, you should have a structure that models the data, e.g. a first name field and a last name field.